# how to move all pairs from one std::map to another

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

Suppose I have the following:

```
std::map<KEY,VALUE> m1;
std::map<KEY,VALUE> m2;
```

**What is the most direct way to move all key/value pairs from `m1` into `m2`?**

I would expect:

- m1 to be empty after this operation
- m2 may initially have pairs
- those pairs in m2 that don't have the same key as m1 should be left alone
- those pairs in m2 that have the same key as m1 should be overwritten with m1's pairs

Do I need a combination of calls from `<algorithm>`?

### Solution

**James Kranze's** solution satisfies my requirements.

```
for( const auto& p : m1 )
  m2[ p.first ] = p.second;
m1.clear();
```

**Joachim Pileborg's** recommendation will only work if m2 and m1 do not have the same key (ie m2's value will not be overwritten by m1's value for the same key)

```
std::move( m1.begin(), m1.end(), std::inserter( m2, m2.begin() ));
```

Comment: Are element copies allowed? Or you literally mean "move" in the language sense?

Comment: It is at times like this that you come to actually appreciate `list::splice`. It's quite surprising, when you think about it, that associative containers have no interface to exchange their nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious solution is just to write a loop yourself:

```
for ( std::map<KEY, VALUE>::const_iterator current = m1.begin();
        current != m1.end();
        ++ current ) {
    m2[current->first] = current->second;
}
```

Otherwise, I think something like the following should work:

```
std::copy( m2.begin(), m2.end(), std::inserter( m1, m1.end() ) );
m2.clear();
m2.swap( m1 );
```

This isn't exactly intuitive, and I'd hesitate to use it without
comments, since:

1. Since `std::map` doesn't have `push_back` or `push_front`, you need
   to use the more general `insterter`, which in turn requires an iterator
   specifying where the insertion is to take place.  Except that `std::map`
   treats this iterator as a “hint”, and since it generally won't be a
   good hint, it will be ignored.
2. You actually have to copy from `m2` into `m1`, since insertion into a
   map will not overwrite any existing value, and when the key is present
   in both maps, you want to keep the value from `m1`.

Comment: +1 this looks good - your point 2. is key as to why std::move(), on its own, is insufficient for my requirements - ty

Comment: Does `m2[std::move(current->first)] = std::move(current->second);` could avoid some copy in this case ? (if KEY and VALUE are std::string for example)

Comment: @ThomasPetit: You could move `second`, but not `first`, since map keys are immutable.

Comment: @ThomasPetit Changing a simple expression such as `m2[current->first] = current->second;` by adding `move`---anywhere in the expression, is premature optimization.  Keep it simple (and in this case, keep it portable as well), until the profiler says you don't have a choice.