# How to iterate over a std::map and move all key-values that satisfy a certain predicate into another std::map?

Tags: c++

Consider we have

```
std::map<int, std::string> m;
```

I want to iterate over m, and move all key-value pairs that satisfies a certain predicate into `std::map<int, std::string> m2`. `m2` is empty at the start, and `m` could be very large, so I want it to be done in one pass.

The operation is kind of splitting the map `m` into `m2` and a new map  `m`.

I know there are something like [`std::move`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585083/how-to-move-all-pairs-from-one-stdmap-to-another), however, it does not support custom predicate like `[](const auto &) { if(...) return true else return false; }`.

Comment: Anything wrong with a simple loop that inspects elements one at a time, and for elements that match, inserting into `m2` and erasing from `m1`?  Note that `map.erase()` invalidates only the affected iterator(s), allowing the loop to continue, provided you increment before deleting.  Don't forget the hint iterator when inserting, so that does better than O(log N).  Perhaps consider requesting a [codereview.se] when you're done.

Comment: If you are using at least C++17, it is possible to use the `extract()` member function in order to remove a node from `m1` and then insert it into `m2`.

Comment: @LoS could it break iterators?

Comment: @calvin, `extract()` invalidates only the iterator that points to the element. However, pointers and references remains valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use the `copy_if` algorithm with move iterators:

```cpp
std::copy_if(
    std::make_move_iterator(m.begin()), 
    std::make_move_iterator(m.end()),
    std::inserter(m2, m2.end()),
    [](auto const& kv) { return kv.first < 2; }
    // ^^^^^^^ dummy predicate, insert your logic here.
);
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32f34fe1dfc1ef39)

if you have any doubts that zero copies are performed during the invocation of `copy_if` here's the same demo with a non copyable type:

[Demo with non copy-able type](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6a4b27cd99c2e1d)

So the real question is what state do you want the original `m` to be in when you're finished. If you simply want to pluck away some values and are not going using `m` afterwards, the above is a convenient way to leave it with some "moved-from" elements. If you want to extract some nodes and keep using `m`, then [use `.extract`](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37fdfbb1602f5b06):

```cpp
for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); )
{
    if (it->first < 2) { // Your predicate goes here.
        m2.insert(m.extract(it++));
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: It leaves the original map in a messy state though, doesn't it? If the original map (with the moved from elements removed) isn't needed, one could simply turn it around and just _erase_ the elements not wanted in it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was just commenting the same thing. The question states they want to "move some kv pairs", it's not clear what they intend to do with the original container. Hence the edit you see above

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. _"If you simply want to pluck away some values and are not going using `m` afterwards"_ ... then just `erase()` those you don't want.

Comment: Also, they _Key_ must be copyable if you use the move-iterator approach.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Avoid `erase()` if you are going to discard the initial tree. It's not equivalent to individual moves since each `erase` operation can trigger a tree rebalancing and the amortized constant time will be greater than simply stealing contents. In the "extract" node case there is more work involved for the same reason.

Comment: Ok, I find that I missed some information and make my question misleading. What I want is kind of splitting the original map `m` into a `m` and `m2`. And `m` and `m2` added up to the original `m`. So basicly, I have to use the second one?

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou According to my benchmarks, the version using the move-iterators is the slowest of the three variants and you are still left with a map in a state where you need to call `clear()` (on the whole map - or each individual _Value_) to make use of it. I see no benefit with it. [Here's my benchmark](https://quick-bench.com/q/2uly-TrecsSV9UcHb9hjYPV1lKg)

Comment: ... and if the _Key_ is something that is more expensive to copy, like a `std::string`, it will be _a lot_ worse to use the move iterators.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The erase function in your benchmark does not actually push the erased elements in a new (`m2`) container. So it's comparing apples with oranges. Both other functions move the selected items in a new container ... but I guess you already know that

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou That's what I been saying since my first comment. If `m` isn't going to be used afterwards, then turn it around and instead of moving elements _from_ it and then discarding it, just remove the elements you don't want from it. Same end result but more efficient.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Also here is the same benchmark where the copy move is run first and clocks in as faster https://quick-bench.com/q/SyYAhUyxdOAZdzZKr-ZJW90yVVQ ...

Comment: @TedLyngmo If >= 50% of the original container is selected then yes that's a viable strategy, but I've operated with the assumption that few(er) elements are actually extracted. I guess my assumption was arbitrary as well, as is the choice to strip 50% of the container in a benchmark

Comment: @calvin Yes, you can't use the first snippet if you want the original container

Comment: "_the copy move is run first and clocks in as faster"_ - It's still slower than erasing, but surprisingly that ordering made a huge difference and made it closer in speed. Mind blown :) Anyway, that's only as long as the _Key_ is cheap to copy.  If it's not, then the _CopyMove_ version becomes very expensive. Yes, I made it 50% since I didn't know if it was going to be 25%, 75% or anything else.

Answer (score 5):

We can extract matching nodes from the source list, and insert them into the destination.  That just requires a single pass over the map.  Since we're not creating new nodes, there's no memory allocation involved:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

template<typename Key, typename Value, typename Pred>
void move_if(std::map<Key, Value>& from,
             std::map<Key, Value>& to,
             Pred predicate)
{
    auto in = from.begin();
    while (in != from.end()) {
        if (predicate(*in)) {
            auto next = std::next(in);
            auto node = from.extract(in);
            to.insert(to.end(), std::move(node));
            in = next;
        } else {
            ++in;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we pass `to.end()` as a hint to `insert()`, since each element we splice belongs *after* all the previous ones.  This makes insertion amortised O(1) per element.

---

Demo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_values(std::ostream& out, std::map<int, std::string> const& values)
{
    const char *sep = " ";
    for (auto const& e: values) {
        out << sep << e.first << '=' << e.second;
        sep = ", ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> odds = {
        { 0, "zero" },
        { 1, "one" },
        { 2, "two" },
        { 3, "three" }};
    std::map<int, std::string> evens;

    move_if(odds, evens, [](auto const& e) { return e.first % 2 == 0; });

    std::cout << "Odd: ";
    print_values(std::cout, odds);
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "Even: ";
    print_values(std::cout, evens);
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```